# Ninject Transient Scope with Dispose

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, scope, ninject

I have a console app that uses `kernel.Get<SomeClass>();` However, `SomeClass` has a dependency on `SomeDisposableClass`. How can I set up my binding to dispose of `SomeDisposableClass` when `SomeClass` is garbage collected? My MVC app uses `InRequestScope` and that works great, but there doesn't seem to be an analogous scope for console apps.

Example here:

```
public class SomeClass {
    public SomeClass(SomeDisposableClass c) {
        this.C = c;
    }

    private SomeDisposableClass C { get; set; }

    // ... Business Methods ... //
}
```

My module

```
kernel.Bind<ISomeClass>().To<SomeClass>().In???Scope()
```

My console app

```
public static void Main() {
    SomeFunc();
    SomeFunc();
    Console.ReadLine();
}

public static void SomeFunc() {
    ISomeClass someClass = kernel.Get<ISomeClass>();
    // work
}
```

I'd like for `SomeDisposableClass` to be disposed when `SomeFunc` is finished (or when the garbage collector is called). But I'm not sure of which binding scope to use. `InTransientScope` doesn't ever call dispose. Do I just have to make `SomeClass` disposable and implement `Dispose()` and wrap all my usages in the console app with a `using` statement?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Ninject2, you can do this by:

```
Bind<IService>().To<ServiceImpl>().InScope(ctx => ...);
```

For example, the callback used for `InRequestScope()` is:

```
ctx => HttpContext.Current
```

Since `HttpContext.Current` is set to a new instance of `HttpContext` on each web request, only a single instance of the service will be activated for each request, and when the request ends and the `HttpContext` is (eventually) collected, the instances will be deactivated.

You can have a static variable within your console to reference an object that will control lifetime.

```
public static object LifetimeController = new object();
```

You can register this as your lifetime control object

```
Bind<IService>().To<ServiceImpl>().InScope(ctx => LifetimeController);
```

And each time you want to refresh the objects you can have a method like this

```
public static void StartNewLifetime()
{
    LifetimeController = new object();
}
```

See [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ninject/usm3b93ZYw4) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18655915/ninject-dbcontext-windows-service-new-instance-each-time-thread-runs/18656636#18656636) for more information

Comment: I upvoted because this is awesome ... but I can't seem to get it working with a test.  You would need to have `SomeClass` implement `IDisposable`, would you not?  And Ninject should then call `Dispose()` on the previous `SomeClass` instance when you invoke `StartNewLifetime()`?  Anyway, not my question, so I will step aside so the OP may render a verdict ...

Comment: @McGarnagle Here's the detail: The object returned by the callback can also implement `INotifyWhenDisposed`, an interface from `Ninject`, if you want to deterministically deactivate the "owned" instances. If the scoping object implements this interface, when it is Dispose()'d, any instances it owns will be deactivated immediately.

Comment: I marked this as the answer.  What I ended up doing was `Bind<IService>().To<ServiceImpl>().InScope(ctx => new object());` this gives me a new object every time and still GCs the ServiceImpl.  I did have to wait for garbage collection, but when I did GC.Collect() it did indeed free the dependent disposable object.

Answer (score -1):

Use `InTransientScope` -- then the Ninject container will not hold any reference to the object.  That way `SomeClass` will be GC'd when it goes out of scope at the end of `SomeFunc`.  All you need to do is have its finalizer dispose of the `SomeDisposableClass` instance:

```
public class SomeClass : IDisposable {
    ~SomeClass() {
        if (this.C != null) this.C.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Here's how I was testing:

```
class Program
{
    private static IKernel _kernel;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        _kernel = new StandardKernel();
        _kernel.Bind<ISomeClass>().To<SomeClass>().InTransientScope();

        while (true)
        {
            LifetimeController = new object();
            SomeFunc();
            Thread.Sleep(10);
        }
    }

    public static void SomeFunc()
    {
        _kernel.Get<ISomeClass>();
    }

    public interface ISomeClass { }
    public class SomeClass : ISomeClass
    {
        public SomeDisposableClass C = new SomeDisposableClass();
        ~SomeClass()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} finalized", this);
            C.Dispose();
        }
    }
    public class SomeDisposableClass : IDisposable
    {
        private byte[] bytes = new byte[1000000];
        public void Dispose()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} disposed", this);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This was another option I was thinking of.  I knew that the finalizer would be called. Thanks for this.